# How do I make sure one Subcription finishes before another?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

```
globleVariable: any;

ngOnInit() {
    // This doesn't work. methodTwo throws error saying "cannot read someField from null. "
    this.methodOne();
    this.methodTwo();
}

methodOne() {
    this.firstService.subscribe((res) => { this.globleVariable = res });
}

methodTwo() {
    this.secondService.subscribe((res) => { console.log(this.globleVariable.someField) });
}
```

As shown above, `methodOne` set the value of `globleVariable` and `methodTwo` uses it, therefore the former must finish running before the latter.

I am wondering how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscribing in the methods, combine them into one stream and subscribe to that in *ngInit()*.  You can use *tap* to perform the side effect of updating *globaleVariable* that you were previously performing in *subscribe()*.

In the example below the "methods" are converted into fields since there is no reason for them to be methods anymore (you can keep them as methods if you want).  Then the ***concat*** operator is used to create a single stream, where *methodOne$* will execute and then when it's complete, *methodTwo$* will execute.

Because *concat* executes in order, you are guaranteed that *globaleVariable* will be set by *methodOne$* before *methodTwo$* begins.

```
globleVariable: any;
methodOne$ = this.someService.pipe(tap((res) => this.globleVariable = res));
methodTwo$ = this.someService.pipe(tap((res) => console.log(this.globleVariable.someField));

ngOnInit() {
  concat(this.methodOne$, this.methodTwo$).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. What if `methodOne$` contains some nested Subcriptions and I want all of them to be finished before running `methodTwo$`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subject for which observable 2 will wait to subscribe like below :-

```
globalVariable: any;

subject: Subject = new Subject();

methodOne() {
    this.someService.subscribe((res) => { this.globleVariable = res; this.subject.next(); });
}

methodTwo() {
    this.subject.pipe(take(1), mergeMap(() => this.someService)).subscribe((res) => { 
          console.log(this.globleVariable.someField) });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarantee a method call after a subscription yields is to use the subscription callbacks.

[Subscriptions](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription) have two main callbacks a success and a failure.

So the way to implement a method call after the subscription yeilds is to chain it like this:

```
globleVariable: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.methodOne();
}

methodOne() {
    this.someService.subscribe((res) => {
       this.globleVariable = res
       this.methodTwo(); // <-- here, in the callback
    });
}

methodTwo() {
    this.someService.subscribe((res) => { console.log(this.globleVariable.someField) });
}
```

You might want to chain the calls with some other [rxjs operators](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators) for a more standard usage.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.method1.pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(res1 => this.globleVariable = res1)
    switchmap(res1 => this.someService.method2), // <-- when first service call yelds success
    catchError(err => { // <-- failure callback
                console.log(err);
                return throwError(err)
            }),
  ).subscribe(res2 => { //  <-- when second service call yelds success
    console.log(this.globleVariable.someField) });
  });
}
```

Please remember to complete any subscriptions when the component is destroyed to avoid the common [memory leak](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject).

Comment: Thanks. For the first approach, I think nesting one inside another is bad for readability. For the 2nd approach, the two methods are rid of, but what if the current code structure is preferred? In other words, the two methods have their unambiguous purposes, and grouping code inside these two methods makes the code easy to understand. In this case, can I achieve my goal while keeping the 2 methods?

Answer (score 0):

my take,

so it's a bit confusing when you use same service that throws different results, so instead of `someService` I used `firstService` and `secondService` here.

```
this.firstService.pipe(
  switchMap(globalVariable) => 
    this.secondService.pipe(
      map(fields => Object.assign({}, globalVariable, { someField: fields }))
    )
  )
).subscribe(result => {
  this.globalVariable = result;
})
```

What I like about this approach is that you have the flexibility on how you want to use the final result as it is decoupled with any of the property in your class.